# Struggling with logic for checking consecutive data entries

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to handle a tricky little situation I've found myself in this morning. I have an entries table in my database where I store details about users' monthly entries (information capture stuff) - I want to increment the number (not the ID) of each entry once a month has passed. The idea is to use the "number" field to be able to identify consecutive monthly entries and to disregard entries within close proximity to one another.

When a user visits the site to start a new entry, I check the date of the last entry completed to see if it is more than 21 days ago (which qualifies as being a valid month) then I increment the "number" for this new entry. The problem is that I can end up with a sequence of entries which are all less than 21 days apart (and thus all have the same number), but collectively span more than 21 days! I need to be able to find some logic to handle this - anyone have any ideas?

An example of how this data is stored, and the problem I'm having, can be seen below.

```
+------+--------+------------+------------+----------------------------+
| id   | number | initiated  | updated    | last_category_reached      |
+------+--------+------------+------------+----------------------------+
|    4 |      1 | 1277914181 | 1277914320 | complete                   |
|  105 |      2 | 1282639343 | 1283444717 | complete                   |
|  397 |      3 | 1284999429 | 1285001298 | complete                   |
|  404 |      3 | 1287478550 | 1287478631 | complete                   |
|  636 |      3 | 1287479243 | 1287479377 | complete                   |
|  649 |      3 | 1287581361 | 1287581466 | complete                   |
|  652 |      3 | 1287585123 | 1287585365 | complete                   |
|  656 |      3 | 1290185205 | 1290424128 | complete                   |
| 1105 |      3 | 1292421193 | 1292426686 | complete                   |
| 1106 |      3 | 1292426769 | 1292426870 | complete                   |
+------+--------+------------+------------+----------------------------+
```

My php logic is below...

```
public function update_entry($stage = NULL)
    {
        // Get last number entered for this user
        $last_entry = $this->last_entry();

        // If part one, user profile is calling the update (passing the next stage as a param)
        if ($stage === 'user/profile/2?s=p_prof&p=2')
        {
            // Only at this stage do we ever create a new entry
            $entry = ORM::factory('data_entry');

            // If no previous sessions, start from 1
            if ($last_entry === FALSE)
                $num = 1; 

            //Here we need to check the time period elapsed since the last submission
            else
            {
                // Check if time difference between last visit and current time is less than 49 days and more than 21 days
                if (($last_entry->initiated > time() - 4233600) && ($last_entry->initiated < time() - 1814400))
                {
                    // Within allowed timeframe, ok to increment by one as a new entry
                    $num = $last_entry->number + 1;
                }
                // More than 49 days since last visit
                elseif (($last_entry->initiated < time() - 4233600)) 
                {
                    // Increment by two to break consecutive entries
                    $num = $last_entry->number + 2;
                }
                // Entry is within the last 21 days - if user never finished stages, use last entry created instead of creating a new one
                else
                {
                    // If they are back at the start having completed a full entry the last time, ok to create a new entry - otherwise use the one created the last time
                    if ($last_entry->last_category_reached !== 'complete')
                        $entry = $last_entry;

                    $num = $last_entry->number;
                }

            }

            // Save the rest of the data for a new entry
            $entry->number = $num;
            $entry->initiated = time();
            $entry->updated = time();
            $entry->last_category_reached = $stage;
            $entry->user_id = $this->id;
            $entry->save();
        }
        // If it's been more than 49 days since last part completion of an entry, user won't be given option to finish the entry, so no need for time check here
        elseif ($stage !== NULL)
        {
            // This must be a continuation of a form, not the beginning of a new one
            // Just update the stage reached and save
            $last_entry->last_category_reached = $stage;
            $last_entry->updated = time();
            $last_entry->save();
            // Assign to $entry for return
            $entry = $last_entry;
        }

        return $entry;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the the last data entry session
     * @return 
     */
    public function last_entry()
    {
            return $this
                    ->limit(1)
                    ->data_entries
                    ->current();
    }
```

Comment: incrementing your timestamp with 4233600 will not take into consideration daylight time changes, try something like `time() - (time() - strtotime('- 49 days'))`

Comment: This is a little too abstract. The right logic depends on information we don't have about the true business requirements for this application. There's a potentially large disconnect between the original goal and the solution you came up with that we can't measure in order to know if a suggestion based on your current scheme is in line with the requirements or veering further away. If you forced me to throw out an idea, it would be to uniquely identify groups of entries, rather than reuse incrementing numbers. Determine if the latest entry should be part of the last group or not.

Comment: Thanks Dan, you're right - it's difficult to explain concisely! I think @LaGrandMere has come up with what I was looking for based on my current setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do in pseudo-code :

If there is a previous number, take the entry with max(number) and min(id).
Calculate the delay between the time of this entry and the current time.
If it is less than 21 days, I don't change numbers, if it's more, I change number.

If you apply this, you won't get periods that last more than 21 days.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for - brain wasn't functioning this morning! Wasted some time with inner joins using max(number) and min(id), then realised i just needed to do a a query with order by number desc, id asc limit 1